# Cannot render the react component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NyZzRSTZQ2Y
I follow this video to open an HTML file and JS file in VSC. but I can't render the js file on the web.The hi I am tom hi is not appear on the web.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<title>Random Quote Machine</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/babel" src="./index.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
function App(){
return(
<div> hi I am tom hi </div>
);
}


ReactDom.render(<App/>,document.getElementById("app"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Update the last line in `index.js` to:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById("app"))
```

and it'll work.

**Explanation:**

- **What was wrong in your index.js?**
  Ans: `ReactDOM` is an object which is imported from `react` library to handle the rendering the component. In your code you were accessing `ReactDom`, note the caps are different, you were referring to `ReactDom` instead of `ReactDOM`.

Remember that JavaScript is a case-sensitive language.

Comment: Hey @smarttom, if this solution helped you please consider accepting the solution. Thanks.